# Changing smart indentation of initialization lists to VS2012 in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

After a short while of working with VS2013, I have noticed that smart indentation behavior changed when creating member initializer lists. In previous revision of visual studio (2012), I got my list indented automatically like so:

```
Foo::Foo()
    : ParentFoo()
    , fooMember(7)
    //, so on
{}
```

My issue with current VS2013 is that it not only indents the initializer list automatically, it also discards the indentation as soon as I type colon and the result looks like so:

```
Foo::Foo()
: ParentFoo()
, fooMember(7)
//, so on
{}
```

Is there any way to revert the functionality to VS2012 for this aspect?

*I was indeed able to get rid of VS discarding my indentation by changing `indentation` from `smart` to `block` but that does not help much as it does not indent any code.*

Comment: Did you try under "Tools -> options -> Text Editor -> C/C++ -> Formatting -> Indentation" Here there are number of options you can set indention for the code?

Comment: Yes, I tried to change those options. Most of them are related to `switch` directive however and indentation of brackets. There is no configuration for initialization lists.